# Split string into multiple two-word strings

Tags: r, string, text, split, strsplit

I have a very long string (~1000 words) and I would like to split it into two-word phrases.

I have this:

```
string <- "A B C D E F"
```

and I would like this:

```
"A B"
"B C"
"C D"
"D E"
"E F"
```

The long string has already been cleaned and stemmed, and stop-words have been removed.

I tried to use str_split, but (I think) this needs a separator, which here is complicated because I don't want to separate A from B only "A B" from "C D", and "B C" from "D E", etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
tmp <- strsplit(string, " ")[[1]]
tmp
# [1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F"
sapply(seq_along(tmp)[-1], function(z) paste(tmp[z-1:0], collapse = " "))
# [1] "A B" "B C" "C D" "D E" "E F"
```

Answer (score 2):

Split on space, then *paste* with shift:

```
s <- unlist(strsplit(string, " ", fixed = TRUE))
sl <- length(s)
paste(s[1:(sl-1)], s[2:sl])
# [1] "A B" "B C" "C D" "D E" "E F"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you already use some text mining package (as cleaned, stemmed and removed stop-words would suggest), there's most likely something to generate n-grams (and not just bigrams). For example `quanteda::tokens_ngrams()` or `tidytext::unnest_ngrams()`:

```r
string <- "A B C D E F"

quanteda::tokens_ngrams(quanteda::tokens(string), concatenator = " ")
#> Tokens consisting of 1 document.
#> text1 :
#> [1] "A B" "B C" "C D" "D E" "E F"

data.frame(s = string) |>
  tidytext::unnest_ngrams(input = "s", output = "bigrams", n = 2)
#>   bigrams
#> 1     a b
#> 2     b c
#> 3     c d
#> 4     d e
#> 5     e f
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-31 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

An option would be to use a regex with look ahead.

```
string <- "A B C D E F"

. <- gregexpr("\\S+\\s+(?=(\\S+))", string, perl=TRUE)[[1]]
attr(.,"match.length") <- attr(.,"match.length") + attr(., "capture.length")
regmatches(string, list(.))[[1]]
#[1] "A B" "B C" "C D" "D E" "E F"
```